# Form AND formset at the same time in ONE step of Formwizard

Tags: django, django-forms, django-formwizard

How can I have in one step of my FormWizard a form and a formset together like I would do in a normal view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have found is to add the forms directly in my context returned to the view, and then in process_step to treat the forms.

I hope this will help!